# Воспроизведение аудио из настроек

Tags: android

Есть экран настроек с `CheckBoxPreference`, также есть сервис, который проигрывает аудиофайл. Можно ли запустить этот сервис при активации `CheckBoxPreference`, а если галочку убрать, то останавливать сервис?

Сейчас я в `MainActivity` через `SharedPreferences` проверяю нажата ли галочка и если нажата, то запускаю, если не нажата, то останавливаю. Но сервис запускается или останавливается при переходе в `MainActivity`, а хотелось бы, чтобы это все происходило прям на экране настроек.

Сам экран настроек settings.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<PreferenceScreen xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:key="preferenceScreen" >

    <PreferenceCategory android:title="Звуки">

        <CheckBoxPreference
            android:defaultValue="false"
            android:key="play_music"
            android:title="Фоновая музыка" />

    </PreferenceCategory>

</PreferenceScreen>
```

SettingsActivity.java

```
public class SettingsActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        setContentView(R.layout.activity_settings);

        getFragmentManager().beginTransaction().add(R.id.prefs_content, new SettingsFragment()).commit();
    }

    public static class SettingsFragment extends PreferenceFragment {

        @Override
        public void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            addPreferencesFromResource(R.xml.settings);
        }
    }
}
```

MusicService.java

```
public class MusicService extends Service {

    private MediaPlayer mPlayer;

    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        super.onCreate();

        mPlayer = new MediaPlayer();

        try {

            SharedPreferences musicPrefs = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this);

            AssetFileDescriptor descriptor = getAssets().openFd("audio/" + "audio1" + ".mp3");
            mPlayer.setDataSource(descriptor.getFileDescriptor(), descriptor.getStartOffset(), descriptor.getLength());
            mPlayer.prepare();
            descriptor.close();
        } catch (IOException ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }

        mPlayer.setLooping(true);
    }

    private void releaseMP() {
        if (mPlayer != null) {
            try {
                mPlayer.release();
                mPlayer = null;
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }

    @Override
    public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
        mPlayer.start();
        return super.onStartCommand(intent, flags, startId);
    }

    @Override
    public void onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy();
        releaseMP();
    }

    @Nullable
    @Override
    public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
        return null;
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Это сделать достаточно просто. При запуске приложения когда запускается сервис оставьте проверку на включение, если отключено останавливайте сервис, а при включении или выключении в настройках отправляйте интент в сервис и в onStartCommand брабатывайте операции вкл/выкл. Вот так примерно можно сделать)

Comment: У меня знаете как: В MainActivity при запуске приложения у меня идет проверка, если галка стоит, то сервис запускается, если галка снята, то останавливается. Но я бы хотел, чтобы когда перешли на экран настроек и включили галку, то сервис сразу бы запускался не выходя из экрана настроек, а то у меня сейчас запуск или остановка только в MainActivity

Comment: А то что вы пишите отправлять интент в сервис и там обрабатывать.. Можно поподробнее? или примерчик небольшой?

Comment: Я лично с PreferenceScreen  не работал, поищите возможность перехвата снятия/установки чекбокса, при обработке чека запускайте или останавливайте сервис. Пример с отправкой команд [пруф](http://startandroid.ru/ru/uroki/vse-uroki-spiskom/159-urok-94-service-podrobno-pro-onstartcommand.html)